# MySQL Query trying to (CROSS?) JOIN on one table

Tags: mysql

Been trying to figure this out for a couple hours and hoping for some expert assistance:

I have a single Mysql table with data such as:

```
Date       version   amount
2021-03-01 A         100
2021-03-02 A          35
2021-03-02 B          80
2021-03-03 A           7
2021-03-03 B          90
2021-03-03 C           3
2021-03-03 A           8
2021-03-04 B          15
2021-03-04 C          90
2021-03-04 B          10
```

And trying to get output for each version for every day, with amount populated as '0' for null;
Result:

```
Date        version    SUM(amount)
2021-03-01  A          100
2021-03-01  B            0
2021-03-01  c            0
2021-03-02  A           35
2021-03-02  B           80
2021-03-02  C            0
2021-03-03  A           15
2021-03-03  B           90
2021-03-03  C            3
2021-03-04  A            0
2021-03-04  B           25
2021-03-04  C           90
```

I tried various 'JOIN', 'LEFT JOIN' and 'CROSS JOIN' permutations without success.

```
SELECT distinct c1.date, c2.version
FROM crash_log c1
LEFT OUTER JOIN crash_log c2 ON c1.date = c2.date
GROUP BY c1.date, c2.version
```

(not even messing with the SUM, just trying to get all the rows with this one)

For now, I have a script that does this by brute force: gets DISTINCT date, then get DISTINCT version, then do a nested loop and build an array for each combination.  One trouble is it's not scalable and seems the web connection is timing out before the process finishes on a large set.

I'm thinking there's one (semi-?) efficient query that can do this, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write subqueries to get all the dates and versions. Cross join these to get every combination.

Then left join that with the table to get either the actual value or default to 0 when NULL.

```
SELECT d.date, v.version, IFNULL(c.sum, 0) AS sum
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT date
    FROM crash_log) AS d
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT version
    FROM crash_log) AS v
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT date, version, SUM(amount) AS sum
    FROM crash_log
    GROUP BY date, version) AS c ON d.date = c.date AND v.version = c.version
ORDER BY d.date, v.version
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like your script, but in SQL.
Cross join the distinct dates to the distinct versions and left join to the table and finally aggregation:

```
SELECT d.Date, v.version, COALESCE(SUM(t.amount), 0) sum_amount
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT Date FROM tablename) d
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT version FROM tablename) v
LEFT JOIN tablename t
ON t.Date = d.Date AND t.version = v.version
GROUP BY d.Date, v.version
```

Comment: Thank you!  Totally works, only clicking the other answer because I can only pick one and it has ORDER BY